# Raspberry Pi surveillance camera

Tags: python-3

I am working with a surveillance camera project with a motion sensor and a buzzer on Raspberry Pi, but when I run the code below:

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from gpiozero import Buzzer
from picamera import PiCamera
from datetime import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
buzzer_pin = 24
led_pin = 18
GPIO.setup (24, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup (18, GPIO.OUT)
camera = PiCamera()
pir = MotionSensor (4)

while True:
    pir.wait_for_motion()
    filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.h264")
    camera.start_recording(filename)
    GPIO.output (buzzer_pin, True)
    GPIO.output (led_pin, True)
    sleep(1)
    GPIO.output (buzzer_pin, False)
    pir.wait_for_no_motion(filename)
    GPIO.output (led_pin, False)
    GPIO.output (buzzer_pin, True)
    sleep(1)
    GPIO.output (buzzer_pin, False)
    camera.stop_recording()
```

I get the follwoing output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fisher/Motion_sensor.py", line 22, in <module>
    pir.wait_for_no_motion(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 192, in wait_for_inactive
    return self._inactive_event.wait(timeout)
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

When the motion is detected, and the camera keeps recording until I remove the video file.

Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: This is only tangentially related to the Pi.  It just seems to be an error of understanding Python.

Comment: try `pir.wait_for_no_motion(int(filename))` @KarrarSavior

Comment: I tried pir.wait_for_no_motion(int(filename)) instead and got the following output: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fisher/Motion_sensor.py", line 24, in <module>
    pir.wait_for_no_motion(int(filename))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2018-03-28_02.58.33.h264'

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you exactly what is wrong.

`pir.wait_for_no_motion(filename)`

It seems to be expecting an integer argument but you are passing a string.

Answer (score 0):

I tried pir.wait_for_no_motion(int(filename)) instead and got the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/fisher/Motion_sensor.py", line 24, 
in <module> pir.wait_for_no_motion(int(filename)) ValueError: invalid literal 
for int() with base 10: '2018-03-28_02.58.33.h264
```